# DBpedia JSON Response

Tags: php, json, error-handling, dbpedia

i have a problem with the json response of the DBpedia.

I generate the query with the following code:

```
$resourceName = ($this->name);
$format = 'json';
$query = "
  SELECT  ?key ?onto WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/".$resourceName."> ?onto ?key .
  }";
$searchUrl = 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql?'
            .'query='.urlencode($query)
            .'&format='.$format;
```

Then i execute this with PHP CURL

```
private function curlRequestDbPedia($url, $checkIfExists = 0){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){die('CURL is not installed!');}
    $ch= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_URL,
        $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
        TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $responseJSON = json_decode($response,TRUE);

    if(json_last_error() != 0){
        echo "ERROR: ".json_last_error();   // -.-
    }
    return $responseJSON;
}
```

If i generate a query for "Hamburg"

The query:

```
SELECT  ?key ?onto WHERE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hamburg> ?onto ?key }
```

the CURL request to

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=%0D%0A%09%09SELECT++%3Fkey+%3Fonto+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FHamburg%3E+%3Fonto+%3Fkey+.%0D%0A%09%09%7D&format=json
```

works fine and i get no json_encode error!

But if i ask the DBpedia for "Sweden" i get

```
SELECT  ?key ?onto WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sweden> ?onto ?key }
```

with the URL:

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=%0D%0A%09%09SELECT++%3Fkey+%3Fonto+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSweden%3E+%3Fonto+%3Fkey+.%0D%0A%09%09%7D&format=json
```

and when i try to encode the response from DBpedia, i get an **ERROR: 4** (Syntax Error).

i put the response json data on www.jsonlint.com and the site told me, that on line 2008 where an error.

```
{
"key": {
  "type": "uri",
  "value": "http://got.dbpedia.org/resource/\U00010343\U00010345\U00010334\U00010330\U00010342\U00010334\U00010339\U0001033A\U00010339"
            }, ...
```

[image]

can someone explain me my error? or why it occurs?

and maybe how i do it to work?

my guess is that it is up to the escape-character ("\U00010343....")

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does that line (2008) actually end right after `"http://got.dbpedia.`.  It looks like perhaps you don't have the full output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DBpedia and SPARQL: Query with accent marks does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200673/dbpedia-and-sparql-query-with-accent-marks-does-not-work)